# How to select bunch of rows from DB, if the data is not present then create the row in DB and then select in JS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

The below code is of my node server.

**Requirement:**
Whenever a api gets a request from the client it should pick the data from the DB if the record present. If in case the data is not present then it should insert a new record to the DB then it should give the data back to the client.

```
router.post('/api/getSelectedEmployeeInfoToUpdate', (req, res)=>{
  let obj = req.body;
  if (Object.keys(obj).length === 0) {
    res.status(400).send({'value':'invalid Parameters'});
  }
  const tempVal = '';

  obj.forEach(emp => {
      names += "'" + emp.name + "'" + ',';
  });

  let jsonArray=[];

  obj.forEach(emp=>{

      // Insert some dummy values
    var insertQueryString = `INSERT INTO rostertable_v2(name, month, year, day1, day2, day3, 
    day4, day5, day6, day7) VALUES ('${req.body.name}','${req.body.month}',${req.body.year},
    '${tempVal}','${tempVal}','${tempVal}',
    '${tempVal}','${tempVal}','${tempVal}')`;

    var sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `rostertable_v2`"
    +" WHERE `name` = '" + emp.name +"'"
    +" AND `month` = '" + emp.month +"'"
    +" AND `year` = " + emp.year;

    connection.query(sql_query, (error, rows, fields)=>{
      //callback
      if(!!error){
        console.log('Error in query...' + error);
        res.send({'success':0})
      }else{
        if (rows.length > 0) {
          console.log('/getEmployeeInfoToUpdate: Successfull query');
          // res.send(rows);
          jsonArray.push(rows);
          console.log(jsonArray);

        }else{
          //insert an empty record into the `rostertable`
          connection.query(insertQueryString, (error, result)=>{
            //callback
            if(!!error){
              console.log('Error in query...' + error);
              res.send([{'success':0}]);
            }else{
              if (result.affectedRows > 0) {
                connection.query(sql_query, (error, rows, fields)=>{
                  //callback
                  if(!!error){
                    console.log('Error in query...' + error);
                    res.send({'success':0})
                  } else {
                    // res.send(rows);
                    jsonArray.push(rows);
                  }
                });
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });

  });// obj.forEach

  console.log('Json Array is : ' + jsonArray);
  res.send(jsonArray);
});
```

**My Problem**: I'm unable to get the result!
I used `let jsonArray=[];` to push the result of a query. but at the time of I used `jsonArray` to send the data to the user it is returning nothing?

*I'm not getting what is the reason for this!*

However I do `jsonArray.push(rows)` then the data is stored in below manner

```
[ [ RowDataPacket {
  name: 'Andy',
  month: '0',
  year: 2019} ]]`
```

*How to fix this issue*

*Any help is much Appreciated*

Comment: the code is async, you should send the json after it is inserted

Comment: I'm not sending any data to the user. In case of error only response will be sent to the client. otherwise the rows pushed to the `jsonArray` and at the end it will be sent to the user.

Comment: res.send(jsonData) inst this returning data from your api

Comment: yes, but I did that at end of my api call

Comment: but it is returning before insert. connection.query will execute the callback after you return the data in your case

Comment: could you please edit my code

Comment: now I'm getting this `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` error

Answer (score 0):

Once array is pushed then send res.

```
jsonArray.push(rows);

//Now send res
res.send(jsonArray);
```

In your case you have written `res.send` before fill data in array. And due to the `async` nature of node it's not wait to fill data in array.

Comment: hey thanks for replay, Could you please edit my code